# Notification for password

Tags: android, database

I am currently making an app in android on which I have randomly generated a password in the database when registration is done. I wanted to know how to give the notification for the password right after the registration done?

Comment: what notification you want to give ?

Comment: I have to retrieve the password and display it to the user

Comment: just try the code answer i shared

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

You can learn here to display a local notification from your application.

Answer (score 0):

create listview in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".ListActivity" >

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In onCreate() of your new activity

```
    String[] passwordArray = (String[]) getValues().toArray(new String[alDcCode.size()]);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_listview, passwordArray);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Paste this method

```
 public ArrayList<String> getValues() {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        LocalDatabase DpDataBase = new LocalDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db =DpDataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT passwordColumName FROM " + tableName, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                values.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("passwordColumName")));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
}
```

and your activity_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/label"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:textSize="16dip"
   android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```